# Getting data from another class to main screen in react js and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working for the first time on React and have got stuck at one place. I want to download some data from an API and display it after applying some operations on it. I am able to get the data from web service in a middleware class but not able to get it on my screen. Following is the class in which API code is called:
**API:**
import loadRecognitionSettings from "../api/settings-recognition";
import { SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD, SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE } from "../actions";

```
export default function recognitionSettingsLoaded() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD });
    loadRecognitionSettings("2")
      .then((payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD, payload });
      })
      .catch((payload) => noticeError(payload.statusText)(dispatch));
  };
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
    import { SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD, SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE } from "../actions";

import { createReducer } from "./utils";

const initialState = {
  days: 0,
  active: [],
  tenantId: 0,
};

const handlers = {
  [SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD]: () => initialState,
  [SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE]: (state, action) => action.payload,
};

export default createReducer(initialState, handlers);
```

Action:

```
    import { noticeError } from "./notices";
import loadRecognitionSettings from "../api/settings-recognition";
import { SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD, SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE } from "../actions";

export default function recognitionSettingsLoaded() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD });
    loadRecognitionSettings("2")
      .then((payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD, payload });
      })
      .catch((payload) => noticeError(payload.statusText)(dispatch));
  };
}
```

**This is how I am calling it in my view class:**

```
    import recognitionSettingsLoaded from "../../actions/settings-recognition";
    class Settings extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(recognitionSettingsLoaded());
    pageLoaded("Configuration");
  }

  render() {
    const { dashboard } = this.props;
    console.log(dashboard);
    const { intl } = this.context;
    return (
      <Article primary={true}>
        <Header
          direction="row"
          justify="between"
          size="large"
          pad={{ horizontal: "medium", between: "small" }}
        >
          <NavControl name={getMessage(intl, "Configuration")} />
          <AdminMenu />
        </Header>
        <Box pad={{ horizontal: "medium", vertical: "medium" }}>
          <Heading tag="h4" margin="none">
            {getMessage(intl, "RecognitionLifetime")}
          </Heading>
          <Heading tag="h5" margin="none">
            {getMessage(intl, "DefineIsRecognitionTemporary")}
          </Heading>
          <Box direction="row">
            <CheckBox
              toggle={true}
              defaultChecked={true}
              //   checked={user.active}
              //   onChange={() => this.toggleActiveUser(index)}
            />{" "}
            <Heading tag="h3" margin="none">
              {getMessage(intl, "NewUserActive")}
            </Heading>
          </Box>
          <Heading tag="h3" margin="none">
            {getMessage(intl, "HideAfter")}
          </Heading>
          <Box direction="row">
            <TextInput placeholder="type here" value={dashboard.days} />{" "}
            <Heading tag="h3" margin="none">
              {getMessage(intl, "Days")}
            </Heading>
          </Box>
          <Button
            path="/recognition-settings"
            label={getMessage(intl, "NewUserSave")}
            primary={true}
          />
        </Box>
        <Notices />
      </Article>
    );
  }
}

Settings.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  dashboard: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

Settings.propTypes = {};

Settings.contextTypes = {
  intl: PropTypes.object,
};
Settings.propTypes = {};

const select = (state) => ({
  dashboard: state.dashboard,
});
export default connect(select)(Settings);
```

Comment: We need to see a little more code to find out what is going on. Could you provide the reducer and initial state code?

Comment: @Christiaan I have added reducer and action class also, please check the updated code now

Comment: You are dispatching the same action twice in the `recognitionSettingsLoaded` thunk. You probably want to dispatch the `SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE` when the request succeeds.

Comment: I don't want to use SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE at load, I will use it later on button click. I have removed the extra call. Thankx for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching the same action (`SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD`) while initializing the `loadRecognitionSettings` and receiving the payload.

Your problem will probably be fixed if you change the second dispatch with the `SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE` action.

```
export default function recognitionSettingsLoaded() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_LOAD });
    loadRecognitionSettings("2")
      .then((payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE, payload });
      })
      .catch((payload) => noticeError(payload.statusText)(dispatch));
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SAVE at load, I will use it later on button click. I have removed the extra call. Thankx for pointing it.

Comment: Ok, that is not very clear in your code. For API requests in Redux, I always use the same naming convention to make it more clear: GET_SOCIAL_VALIDITY, GET_SOCIAL_VALIDITY_SUCCESS, GET_SOCIAL_VALIDITY_FAILURE. The names should be self explaining.